Perl, Dancer2 session not working as expected
I've got everything working on my small web app, even payments and hosting. It's just an app that takes scheduling information as input into a database, then it organizes it into a heavily formatted spreadsheet for download. The last thing I realize I need is reliable sessioning. I switched from the "Simple" setting to "Memcached" and then "Cookie" but I noticed the cookies don't expire.
config.yml
session: Cookie
engines:
  session:
    Cookie:
      secret_key: 'Sooper Sekrit Passfraze Hear'
      default_duration:     18000
      with_request_address: 0


The cookie don't expire even if I set default_duration for 18000 seconds. I can walk away for an hour or even stop the plack/Starman server and come back and the web app still picks up from where it left off without having to log back in. I now realize the module doesn't do what I was expecting and that my conceptualization of sessioning might be wrong as well. But there aren't many Dancer2 examples. Can anyone help me out and offer some pointers? I really just want to get something simple working that's reasonably secure. Thanks!

Maybe try setting it to something very low, like 30 seconds, and see what happens then? It might be simpler to test than with a 5 hours expiration.

You're right. I was so busy changing everything else I neglected to pay attention to that value. And my math was wrong as well. Thank you for catching my stupid mistake. I need to call it a day and stop making mistakes for a short while.

That's normal to ask for help. Your settings were actually perfectly right. Please mark the question as solved!
